# Log.io, set latest log from forever automatically

Tags: node.js, forever

I use Forever to automatically restart my app in case of problems. Recently I found out a really nice app to monitor different logs in my server from a browser, which is [log.io](http://logio.org/).

Log.io allows me to set log files to monitor, for example:

```
logStreams: { 
  apache: [ "/var/log/apache2/access.log", "/var/log/apache2/error.log" ] 
},
```

For apache it works like a charm, because the file name is always the same. But forever at each restart of my app creates a totally new file name (`[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{4}.log`).

Is there a way to set a static log file name for forever, or to dynamically set the latest log file in config of log.io?

Which method would you advise?

Comment: Just a comment for anyone having issues with Log.io in windows: Your log.io config files are located in C:\Users\<user<\.log.io\ and not in the node_modules folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the forever documentation, you can define a forever log file with the following forever options.

```
options:
-l  LOGFILE      Logs the forever output to LOGFILE
-o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE
-e  ERRFILE      Logs stderr from child script to ERRFILE
```

so you would do something like this:

```
forever start -l /path/to/log/forever.log -o /path/to/log/myapp.log -e /path/to/log/myapp_error.log
```

you can then configure your log.io harvester

```
logStreams: { 
    myapp: [ "/path/to/log/myapp.log", "/path/to/log/myapp_error.log", "/path/to/log/forever.log" ] 
},
```